# Using JRuby with libGDX desktop runnable JAR

Tags: java, libgdx, jruby

I have a libGDX core and desktop projects in Eclipse. I have put JRuby complete JAR in the core project's build path. If you run the desktop project, it works.

But when you export the desktop project as a runnable jar, the scripting engine returns null because it can't find JRuby. But Jruby is in the build path of the core project!

I tried adding Jruby to the build path of the desktop project, but the same happens. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you export a Runnable JAR file. Don't forget to check:

> > Package required libraries into generated JAR.